# Undefined foreach as option AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, foreach, drop-down-menu

Trying to get subcategories based on category. 
Here is what I get as a response from server :

> [{"id":"1","agname":"xxxx","sim":"xxxxxxxx","del":"0","coorid":"x"}]

Now when I try to display it in a select, I get undefined output just like below:

[image]

PS. I'm not very familiar with Javascript.

Here's my code:

```
$.post("getagents.php", {
    coorid: coorid,
}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#agents').empty();
    $.each(JSON.parse(data, function(index, subAgentObj){
        $('#agents').append('<option value="'+subAgentObj.agname+'">'+subAgentObj.agname+'</option>');
    }))
});
```

**Following @Casper's answer, this is what I get now.**

[image]

Comment: can you please post your codes as well?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to put it, my bad!

Comment: done @sajadHaibat

Comment: Use this $('#agents').append('<option value="'+subAgentObj+'">'+subAgentObj+'</option>');

Comment: Can you show inspect html  of select element?

Comment: Use:  $('#agents').append('<option value="'+subAgentObj['agname']+'">'+subAgentObj['agname']+'</option>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.each` method desiged to run through [all elements](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). In this senario you need loop through array therefore use JavaScript `forEach` method instead of jQuery `$.each` method.

```js
var response = '[{"id":"1","agname":"xxxx","sim":"xxxxxxxx","del":"0","coorid":"x"}]';
JSON.parse(response).forEach((item) => {
  console.log(`id: ${item.id}`)
  console.log(`agname: ${item.agname}`)
  console.log(`sim: ${item.sim}`)
})
```

Comment: I am getting it to display yet it doesn't display the name only. What I need is only to display the name. It displays all of the values of the array

Answer (score 0):

you can use map

```js
let data = JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","agname":"xxxx","sim":"xxxxxxxx","del":"0","coorid":"x"}])


    
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    
    parsedData.map((d, i) =>{
      Object.keys(d).map((di, i) =>{
         $('#agents').append('<option    value="'+parsedData[0][di]+'">'+parsedData[0][di]+'</option>');
    
      })
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="agents"></select>
```

here you know that your response will be an array so you can access through your array and loop it like below

```js
let data = JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","agname":"xxxx","sim":"xxxxxxxx","del":"0","coorid":"x"}])


    
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    
      Object.keys(parsedData[0]).map((di, i) =>{
        $('#agents').append('<option    value="'+parsedData[0][di]+'">'+parsedData[0][di]+'</option>');
    
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="agents"></select>
```